# A graph-api post with a caption fails to show caption in friends feed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Posts show with caption on the original timeline but in a friends feed, the domain of the link is used instead of the caption. This is a big problem for us - clients are complaining, they want to see the proper caption on all iterations of the post.

Steps to repro:

1) log onto facebook

2) go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

3) enter this code (adapted from example code):

```
<fb:login-button scope="read_stream,publish_stream">
  Grant Permissions to make more examples work
</fb:login-button>
<button onclick="doPost()">Post to Stream</button>

<script>
window.doPost = function() {
  FB.api(
    '/me/feed',
    'post',
    { message: 'testing caption friend view',
      link:'http://xetra.tunegenie.com',caption:'caption' },
     Log.info.bind('/me/feed POST callback')
  );
};
</script>
```

4) click "run code" button under code input box

5) click the "post to stream" button (you may need to click the button to add permissions first)

6) note that this post is on your logged in users timeline with the caption text in place of the link (if it is not you may need to click the "add permissions" button")

7) log in with a friend of this user and note that the caption text is not used here and is replaced with the domain of the link used.

Expcted: the caption text should be carried to all iterations of a post.

I think this is a facebook bug, but I was not able to enter a bug report there (maybe you need special privileges for that?) as it appears you should be able to as described here:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/

any info, confirmation or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it definitely sounds like a FB bug.   You have to start searching for a bug in order to create one.

Just start typing text in the **bug search bar** *(not the main top search)*, and you'll see a "Create a bug" option in the resulting dropdown menu -

[image]